# How to store user input in Java

Tags: java

I'm making a simple hangman game. The code below updates the letters so it's checking if the guessed letter is in the word properly. However, it won't store the letter if a second correct letter is guessed. For example, for "moose", if I guess 'o' then it will print out (#oo##), then if I guess 'e', it will print out ####e. Maybe it has something to do with the else statement? I'm fairly new to this so any tips or just documentation would help. Thanks!

```
 public static boolean updateWithGuess(char[] knownLetters,
                                      char guessedLetter,
                                      String word) {
    boolean found = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if(word.charAt(i) == guessedLetter) {
            knownLetters[i] = guessedLetter;
            found = true;
        }
        else {
            knownLetters[i] = BLANK;
            found = false;
        }
    } 
    return found;
}
```

Comment: why do you need `knownLetters[i] = BLANK;`? if all positions are initially blank, there is no need to assign them to blank again

Comment: You're storing the guessed letter in a single char variable, but you're storing the letters of the secret word in a char array. What if... you also stored guessed characters in a second char array and iterated through it when you wanted to know whether the user already guessed it?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the issue isnt in this method, Instead try returning the `char[]` And then the caller of the method will update to that, In the end not caring if its correct or incorrect(Unless if you have some reason not to do this). Also just take out the whole else, That is whats causing your issue because its blanking out the other letters even if they are correct.